# Android Paint.breakText not calculating number of charecters correctly

Tags: android, textview, paint

In my app I am using using a texView to display some text. I am using the below piece of code to wrap text by char.

```
textToBeShown = textToBeShown.replace(' ', '\u00A0');
```

When I calculate the number of characters that fits a line using

```
mTextView.getPaint().breakText(textToBeShown, 0,
                    textToBeShown.length(), true, mTextView.getWidth(), null);
```

it gives me incorrect number of chars (less than actually displayed number) because the `breakText` method calculates the number of chars based on word wrap and not char warp.

Please suggest how I can get correct number of chars using `breakText` method.

Comment: breakText exhibits a bug where ligaturized text sequences (e.g. "fi") are counted as a single character in the returned count when in reality they consume multiple.